# Как поднять дные выше и вывести их PHP 7.1

Tags: php, массивы, веб-программирование, вывод

Всем привет, прошу помочь в решение очень сложного вопроса (Мучаюсь с ним уже 4 дня).

Суть вопроса:
Есть несколько функций, которые собирают данные со страницы объединяют их в третий функции и выводят массивами в нужных местах. Но есть одно но - Данные не хотят выводится выше функций, в которых он передаются.

[image: Как выглядит на сайте]
Получаю данные вот так (код 1):

```
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("h1 документа");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Тайтл");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "Описание");
```

Обрабатываю и объединяю для вывода вот так:

```
// Получаем тег H1 траницы и отправляем в SetMeta() и в ShowTitle($FALSE)
    function SetTitle($H1){
        $this->SetPageProperty('h1',$H1);
    }

    // Получаем title и description и отправвляем в GetPageProperty()
    private $arr = []; 
    public function SetPageProperty($TYPE,$TAGS)
    { 
        $this->arr['TAGS'][$TYPE]=$TAGS; 
    }

    // Объединяем все функции в один массив и передаём в GetPagePropertyList($TYPE);
    public function GetPageProperty(){ 
        return $this->arr; 
    } 

    // Получаем все мета теги сайта и отправвляем в SetMeta()
    public function GetPagePropertyList($TYPE){

        //Получаем данные из БД
        global $arItems,$arParams;

        //Получаем данные из БД
        $this->SetContent();

        if($TYPE=='h1'){
            return $this->arr['TAGS']['h1'];
        }

        if($TYPE=='title'){

            return $this->arr['TAGS']['title'];
        }

        if($TYPE=='description'){
            return $this->arr['TAGS']['description'];
        }

    }
```

Вывожу на страницу вот так:

```
H1 в HEAD
<h1><?=$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?></h1>

TITLE в HEAD                    
<h1><?=$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(" ");?></h1>

description в HEAD
<h1><?=$APPLICATION->GetPagePropertyList('description');?></h1>
```

---

Ошибка заключается в том, что если вставляю код вывода данных после код_1 то всё работает, а если перед то нет. Мне нужно, что бы работало перед кодом_1

---

PHP 7.1

---

Прошу помощи, так как сам уже перепробовал все возможные варианты.

Comment: Копируете битриксовые подходы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не пробовали с `ob_star` `ob_get_contents`?

Сам туплю)) поменял местами

```
ob_start();
echo '<p>код_1</p>';
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

echo "<p>данные</p>";

echo $data;
```

код_1 выведется после вывода данных

Comment: Нет. А как их можно использовать?

Comment: Кстати, идея хороша - в стандартных условиях можно все перетасовать по желанию.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то эти теги для php 5 и 4 а у меня 7.1

Comment: ob_start
(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) офф сайт php

Comment: я просто не пойму, чем вас не устраивает вывод данных после их передачи?

Answer (score 0):

Поместите нужное в переменную, где оно выводится гарантировано, а потом эту переменную выведите к показу там, где Вам нужно вывод сделать. Иного решения не будет - в этом случае, имхо.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что именно нужно поменять местами

Comment: Помещаете функции там, где они отрабатывают (в самом начале файла, например, но не выводите их, а результат/ы помещаете в переменные, которые выводите в нужном месте. То есть, Вы сначала собираете все нужное, а потом оперируете, как Вам удобно - проблем не будет, потому как все уже будет отработано и находиться в переменных.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у меня сейчас всё так и есть. Проблема в том, что я получаю данные пред файлом header.php http://joxi.ru/Y2LbnD4c7z5YMr А выводить хочу в нём. (Данные обрабатываются выше файла header.php)

Comment: Вы подключаете header, а потом получаете данные - по Вашей картинке. В таком случае, перенесите получение в файл header. Или Вам нужно действительно с битриксоводом посоветоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Моё сообщение не является ответом на ваш вопрос, но уж сильно ваш метод режет глаза) По этому я его немного переписал:

```
 public function getPagePropertyList($type)
 {   
      return $this->arr['TAGS'][$type];
 }
```

Не называйте переменные заглавными буквами, так принято называть константы.
Не пользуйтесь глобальными переменными от них больше вреда чем пользы, и зачем вам вызов этого в функции?

```
/Получаем данные из БД
        global $arItems,$arParams;

        //Получаем данные из БД
        $this->SetContent();
```

Так же название set используется для записи, а не для получения данных, для этого служит название get.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Исправил.